# How can I format the index (\printindex) in a specific way?

Tags: imakeidx

I need your help!
[image]

This is how I made it:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Idx.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\hrulefill  \n \n \\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}} \\nopagebreak"

delim_0 "\n\n  \\item  "

group_skip "\n\n \\hrulefill"
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[8.5pt twoside, a4paper]{book} 
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[scaled]{uarial} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 


\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[options=-s Idx.ist]

\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Irgendein Text.
\section{Eins}
Blablabla.
\subsection{Regeln}
\index{Ausland}
\index{Sieger}
\index{Spieler}
\index{Spielfeld}
\subsection{Beschäftigung}
\index{Beruf}
\index{Arbeit}
\vfill
\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Stichwortverzeichnis}}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\fontsize{7.5pt}{0pt}
\printindex 

\end{document}
```

Edit: The section numbering and the thing with a line at the end worked fine! THANKS!
But the indentation does not work. `\struntbox` does not work..

Edit2.0: If I have more indeces, there is a columnbreak within a "group" of alphabetic characters. How can I avoid this?

3rd Edit: I just realized that I need an extra row/line after the groups. Like this:
[image]

How can add such a row/line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Thank you for the MWE.  I edited your question by marking your code and typing `CTRL-K` to format the code as code block.

Comment: Where do the numbers 1.2, 2.1, 3.1 etc. come from?

Comment: Please add comments to an answer as comment to the answer not as edit to the question. BTW: Don't know what you mean with `\struntbox`. I've added the indentation to my answer know.

Comment: You do not need 50 reputation to comment on your own question or answers to it.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1263/289256

Comment: Please read: [Detail in question changed after one answer already given; change question or new question?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2514) and [Follow up questions to answered thread](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3597). I've now reached the limit of three images per answer. So I cannot add additional modifications with additional example images.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the page numbers at the index, simply do not remove them with your redefinition of `\index`. The formatting can be done with some changes of `Idx.ist` and some additional definitions:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Idx.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}"

delim_0 "\\hfill"

group_skip "\n"
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\starttheindex"
postamble "\n\\stoptheindex\\end{theindex}"
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[8.5pt,% book does not know this option (but don't forget the comma!)
  twoside,% this is default
  openany,% so usually you do not need \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
  a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % use new spelling instead of old
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}% uarial is a very ugly mix of Arial and Helvetica 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 


\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[options=-s Idx.ist]

% If you do not want page numbers but, e.g. subsection numbers in the index:
%\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
%\newcommand*{\indexpage}[2]{#1}
%\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|indexpage{\thesubsection}}} 
\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{%
  \indexrule
  \textbf{#1}\par
  \nopagebreak
  \vskip-\baselineskip% go back to the heading line
}
\newcommand*{\indexrule}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \vskip-\ht\strutbox
  \hrulefill\par\pagebreak[3]
  \vskip -\baselineskip
  \hrulefill\par\nobreak
}
\newcommand*{\starttheindex}{\raggedcolumns}
\newcommand*{\stoptheindex}{\indexrule}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent 2em\hskip 1.5em}% indent the entry
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Irgendein Text.
\section{Eins}
Blablabla.
\subsection{Regeln}
\index{Ausland}
\index{Sieger}
\index{Spieler}
\index{Spielfeld}
\subsection{Beschäftigung}
\index{Beruf}
\index{Arbeit}
\vfill
\clearpage% should be used before \addcontentsline

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Stichwortverzeichnis}% the index is a chapter and becomes the font for chapter entries that is already bold
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\fontsize{7.5pt}{0pt}
\printindex 

\end{document}
```

[image: Index with page numbers]

If you remove the `%` in front of

```
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\newcommand*{\indexpage}[2]{#1}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|indexpage{\thesubsection}}}
```

you'll get:

[image: Index with subsection numbers]

To avoid column breaks inside groups you can add an additional `\nopagebreak` in the definition of `\@idxitem`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Idx.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}"

delim_0 "\\hfill"

group_skip "\n"
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\starttheindex"
postamble "\n\\stoptheindex\\end{theindex}"
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[8.5pt,% book does not know this option (but don't forget the comma!)
  twoside,% this is default
  openany,% so usually you do not need \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
  a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % use new spelling instead of old
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}% uarial is a very ugly mix of Arial and Helvetica 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 


\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[options=-s Idx.ist]

% If you do not want page numbers but, e.g. subsection numbers in the index:
%\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
%\newcommand*{\indexpage}[2]{#1}
%\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|indexpage{\thesubsection}}} 
\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{%
  \indexrule
  \textbf{#1}\par
  \nopagebreak
  \vskip-\baselineskip% go back to the heading line
}
\newcommand*{\indexrule}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \vskip-\ht\strutbox
  \hrulefill\par\pagebreak[3]
  \vskip -\baselineskip
  \hrulefill\par\nobreak
}
\newcommand*{\starttheindex}{\raggedcolumns}
\newcommand*{\stoptheindex}{\indexrule}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@idxitem}{\par\nopagebreak\hangindent 2em\hskip 1.5em}% indent the entry
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Irgendein Text.
\section{Eins}
Blablabla.
\subsection{Regeln}
\index{Ausland}
\index{Sieger}
\index{Spieler}
\index{Spielfeld}
\subsection{Beschäftigung}
\index{Beruf}
\index{Arbeit}
\index{Test1}\index{Test2}\index{Test3}\index{Test4}\index{Test5}
\index{Test6}\index{Test7}\index{Test8}\index{Test9}\index{Test10}
\vfill
\clearpage% should be used before \addcontentsline

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Stichwortverzeichnis}% the index is a chapter and becomes the font for chapter entries that is already bold
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\fontsize{7.5pt}{0pt}
\printindex 

\end{document}
```

But I would not recommend this, because you will get overfull columns if a group is larger than the column height.

To change the vertical distance above the rule, just change the line

```
  \vskip-\ht\strutbox
```

in the definition of `\indexrule`, e.g.,

```
\newcommand*{\indexrule}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \vskip\dp\strutbox\nopagebreak
  \hrulefill\par\pagebreak[3]
  \vskip -\baselineskip
  \hrulefill\par\nobreak
}
```

would result in

[image: with gap before the line]

Note that I've used another font, because I do not have the ugly URW-Arial installed.

You should also have a look at the several notes I've added to the code.

Comment: How can I reduce the hspace between the two 'columns'?

Comment: @GuestUser: This is another question. Don't ask questions as comments but ask new questions (see my comment to the question above). Nevertheless, see option `columnsep` in section 3 of the [`imakeidx` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf).